# Security of Datastore Remote API?

Tags: google-app-engine

I would like to use the Datastore Remote API to share data between two GAE applications (http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi.html) 
To do that I understand that I need to add a servlet to my GAE application, but I'm a bit worried about security. Ideally I would like this servlet to be visible only to other GAE applications, but not to other clients outside of Google's datacenters. Is there any way to configure this ?

Answer (score 4):

remote_api is only ever accessible by administrators of your application, unless you configure it otherwise.

Comment: Thanks but if another of my apps is using the remote_api, is this considered an "admin" request, just like cron jobs are ?

Comment: @sdonze Only if you specifically configure remote_api to allow requests from another app (in which case, only that App ID will be allowed).